# $A$ is an $n \times n$ invertible matrix, prove that $f(\mathbf u, \mathbf v)= \mathbf u^TAA^T \mathbf v$ defines an inner product on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have difficulty especially proving that $f(\mathbf v, \mathbf v) \geq 0$ for all $\mathbf v$.

Thanks

Comment: The matrix $A$ isn't invertible?

Comment: For example, if $A=O$ is the zero-matrix then $f(u,v)$ is not an inner product, since $f(u,u)=0$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: yes you're right, A is invertible. I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Let me tackle the bit that you find the most difficult.  Let $x=A^Tv$. Note that

$$v^T A A^T v=x^T x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\geq 0.$$